# Will the sound processor in an iPad outperforms MacBook Pro's?

Tags: audio, quality

So iPads or any other iPod or iPhones uses audio codec from third-parties, most likely Cirrus Logic in recently products. For example, the iPhone 5 uses Apple-branded Cirrus Logic 338S1077 audio codec according to [this iFixit teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+5+Teardown/10525/1).

I am not sure of the codec used in MacBook Pros, especially my 15" retina one, but I am thinking that since the audio is the Intel integrated one, the codec is probably Intel-branded.

But the question remains, which would yield a better quality. The one on MacBook Pro or the one on an iPad or iPhone.

(Assuming playing the same AIFF file, outputting through the headphone port to a same headphone.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Cirrus Logic audio codec  :

Source :

- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/cracking-open/teardown-shows-retina-macbook-pro-is-nearly-impossible-to-upgrade-difficult-to-work-on/696
- http://www.techrepublic.com/photos/cracking-open-the-apple-macbook-pro-with-retina-display/6372862?seq=79

So I would say the iPad won't outperform the MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

My side-by-side comparison on my hi-fi system has revealed to my ears that the macbook outputs a much higher quality sound than an iphone5 and ipad3.